# how to linkify unicode numbers in javascript using regex

Tags: javascript, regex, unicode

How can I change the regex below to also select the unicode numbers? Currently only ASCII numbers are selected.

```js
function numberfy(text) {
    var urlRegex = /[+0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]*)?[0-9]{5,}/g;

    return text.replace(urlRegex, function(url) {
        return '<font color="blue"><u><a href="tel:' + url + '">' + url + '</a></u></font>';
    });
}
```

Thanks

Comment: can you give some example what is test what you want output is?

Comment: yes javascript the input can be 123٧٨٩  the out put should be  same

Comment: do you want to match numbers from any culture or from specific cultures

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is unclear, but if you are looking to include alternate Unicode numeral forms, such as the Unicode full-width characters, you can add in explicit Unicode ranges like this:

```
// Adds the full-width unicode range FF10-FF19 (    ０-９)
var urlRegex = /[+0-9\uFF10-\uFF19]+(?:\.[0-9\uFF10-\uFF19]*)?[0-9\uFF10-\uFF19]{5,}/g;
```

[A working example.](http://jsfiddle.net/YmanU/)  You can add additional ranges simply by tacking them on.  I'd be tempted to modify your code so you could reduce the duplication if you have more than a few ranges:

```
var digit = "0-9\uFF10-\uFF19";
var urlRegex = new RegExp("[+"+digit+"]+(?:\\.["+digit+"]*)?["+digit+"]{5,}", "g");
```

A list of [alternate Unicode numeric forms can be found here](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Nd/list.htm).  This includes other forms in other languages.

Please note that only 2-byte Unicode values will work (up to `\uFFFF`).  On that page they include some extended forms (Mathematical Bold, for example) that are outside the 2-byte Unicode range supported by JavaScript.

Comment: Here's [an example with the concatenated string for the regex](http://jsfiddle.net/yqnYr/) — sorry if my typo of `Regex` instead of `RegExp` caused an error earlier.

Comment: JavaScript can handle characters outside BMP range, but it will become a bit ugly when you use regex, since you have to consider 1 character as 2 characters in JS String. (My point here is that it is possible to use regex to handle those characters outside BMP).

Comment: the above regex does not work when i add these unicode numbers ٠١٢٣٤٥٦٧٨٩

Comment: @skcrpk: Of course it does not work. This answer is to **guide** you on how to construct the regex yourself, not to **spoonfeed** you with the solution.

Answer (score 1):

In `Javascript` you would have to include unicode number range for every culture.

You can specify the range using `\uxxxx` where x is hexadecimal..

So you can match digits of specific cultures like

```
[\u0966-\u096F]+//matches `Devangiri` digits
[\u0E50-\u0E59]+//matches `Thai` digits

[\d\u0966-\u096F\u0E50-\u0E59]+//matches `Thai`,`Devangiri`,`ascii` digits
```

You can find unicode number range for all cultures [here](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Nd/list.htm)

---

Instead you can use [xregexp](http://xregexp.com/plugins/#unicode) library in which you can use

`\p{N}` to match any Unicode number

---

If you are interested in complete range that covers all cultures.

> 0030-003900B200B300B900BC-00BE0660-066906F0-06F907C0-07C90966-096F09E6-09EF09F4-09F90A66-0A6F0AE6-0AEF0B66-0B6F0B72-0B770BE6-0BF20C66-0C6F0C78-0C7E0CE6-0CEF0D66-0D750E50-0E590ED0-0ED90F20-0F331040-10491090-10991369-137C16EE-16F017E0-17E917F0-17F91810-18191946-194F19D0-19DA1A80-1A891A90-1A991B50-1B591BB0-1BB91C40-1C491C50-1C5920702074-20792080-20892150-21822185-21892460-249B24EA-24FF2776-27932CFD30073021-30293038-303A3192-31953220-32293248-324F3251-325F3280-328932B1-32BFA620-A629A6E6-A6EFA830-A835A8D0-A8D9A900-A909A9D0-A9D9AA50-AA59ABF0-ABF9FF10-FF19

Refer [here](http://xregexp.com/addons/unicode/unicode-categories.js)

Answer (score -1):

From Comment @Alexey i updated my answer:

in you comment "123٧٨٩" thease are arabic digits

```
 ARABIC-INDIC DIGIT---> \u0660-\u0669
 EXTENDED ARABIC-INDIC DIGIT---> \u06F0-\u06F9
```

try this pattren

```
[+0-9\u0660-\u0669\u06F0-\u06F9]+(?:\.[0-9\u0660-\u0669\u06F0-\u06F9]*)?[0-9\u0660-\u0669\u06F0-\u06F9]{5,}
```

if you want any unicode symbol then you can search that symbol here http://www.ltg.ed.ac.uk/~richard/unicode-sample-3-2.html

Comment: It seems you're trying to match phone numbers and Unicode escape code, right? But what the author of question actually asks for is the same pattern as he has, but that is culture-independent. That includes not only Latin number characters, but something like Devangiri and Thai as well.